# how to retrieve nodejs scraped data and display in html

Tags: html, node.js, angularjs, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape a website for some content using NodeJs, it all works good but then the **scraped** text is desplayed in the console only however, i want to pass my **scraped** data to my html page (index.html), but didn't know how to do that.

here is my nodejs file (scrape.js)

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals', (error, response, html) =>{
if(!error && response.statusCode == 200){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

  $('.title').each((i,ele) => {
      const title = $(ele).text();
      console.log(title);
  });

}
})
```

and here is my html file where the data should displayed in(index.html)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Real Time Data</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div class="bgimg w3-display-container w3-animate-opacity w3-text-white">
        <div class="w3-display-topleft w3-padding-large w3-xlarge">
            Real Time Data
        </div>
        <div class="w3-display-middle">
            <h1 class="w3-jumbo w3-animate-top">Real Time Data</h1>
            <center>
                <div id="getDDta">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Title</th>
                        </tr>

                        <tr>
                            <td>Data...</td>
                        </tr>
                        </table>
                </div>
            </center>
        </div>
        <div class="w3-display-bottomleft w3-padding-large">
            Powered by
             Real Time Data</a>
         </div>
        </div>
        </body>
      </html>
```

my request is very simple, i want to display the **scraped** data in nodejs (scrape.js) in (index.html)

Comment: Hi there! There are multiple ways to achieve the outcome you desire, however, I would suggest you make use of a templating engine. You can check out [ejs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ejs). The templating engine can help you manage how you pass and transform data into markups.

Comment: FYI it’s __scraped__ (and __scrape__, __scraping__, __scraper__) not scrapped

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use EJS (or perhaps any other templating engine) for this purpose.

We download the titles to an array, then render using ejs.render.

Make sure you install ejs using

```
npm install ejs
```

In your project you'll need to create the following structure:

- /index.js
- /views/index.ejs

**index.js**

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const express = require('express');

var app = express();
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    request('https://store.steampowered.com/search/?filter=weeklongdeals', (error, response, html) => {
        if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            const $ = cheerio.load(html);
            let titles = [];
            $('.title').each((i,ele) => {
                const title = $(ele).text();
                console.log(title);
                titles.push(title);
            });
            res.render('index', { titles });
        }
    })

});

app.listen(8080);
console.log('Express listening on port 8080');
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Real Time Data</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body style="padding: 2em">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
        <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        </tr>
        <% for (let title of titles) { %>
        <tr>
        <td><%= title %></td>
        </tr>    
        <% } %>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Then navigate to localhost:8080/ to see your rendered page.

I've created an online example [here](https://repl.it/@GarethRoddy/VividClosedCosmos)

Comment: thanks bro, it works fine now, one thing i wanna ask, how can i access to array title and get index element? for example (title.[0])

Comment: You could use titles[0] for example to access array elements in the .ejs page. I'm using a for .. of loop but you could use a regular for loop too.

Comment: E.g. use <% for (let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) { %> in place of <% for (let title of titles) {  and use <td><%= titles[i] %></td> in place of <td><%= title %></td>.

Comment: hi bro, i have tried ur example and i got the right index element, but the problem is i got it as a duplicate data when i use title[0] e.g. (rust, rust, rust). what u think the problem?

Comment: Oh hey, you need to loop over the titles like <% for(let i =0..., then use titles[i] in the <td> element. That should do it!

Comment: yeah bro, i have used that and it works somehow, but the thing is when i try to fetch specific element in the array like: for(let i = 0; i < titles.length; i++){
                console.log(titles[1]);
            }, it fetch the right element but it duplicate it three times

Comment: Oh sorry,  my mistake. You should be able to just reference a specific element by skipping the outer loop. Just include a <td><%= titles[2] %></td> element (or just a p, h1 etc. element or whatever!)

Comment: it works now. thank you very much bro, you have been more than helpful

Comment: Great! Glad to be of help!!

Answer (score 0):

What @Terry said, but use get and map rather than pushing elements in an each loop:

```
let titles = $('.title').get().map(e => $(e).text())
```